# Disabling old domain users from Person Picker

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-accounts, domain

I have SharePoint 2013 eviorment, There are 2 types of domain users in SharePoint, lets say, that they are `old.contoso.com` that are old domain users and `contoso.com` that are new domain users.

**Situation:**

Now I have a problem, that in default `Person picker` selects `old.contoso.com` domain users, but people are logged in to SharePoint with `contoso.com` users and when there should be approval tasks or other permission dependent occurrence, then that person can't work with those items (since he/she is logged in with different account).

**What I have thought of:**

1. Removing all `old.contoso.com` users from SharePoint, but doesn't it affect old documents, if that user can't be find anymore?
2. `Move-SPUser` - could it work with my current situation?

How could I resolve this situation?

Comment: did you migrated the user from old to new domain? are there any trust between Domains? on which domain SharePoint installed?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, how it has been done, since I wasn't part of moving to new users, that are in the new domain now. I think, that they just took new users to use and left old ones, as they are.

Answer (score 2):

The users from the old domain are still part of the site collection in something called User Information List. This list populates the people picker. You would have to delete the old users from the User Information List which can be found in `http://SiteCollectionURL/_catalogs/users`.

When you have deleted the users from the User Information List, and the user access the site collection again, the new user information will appear in the user information list. If there are no records in the user information list, the people picker will find information from the User Profile Service (if available) or the Active Directory.

Comment: But wouldn't it affect document `Creator`, `Modified By` etc.. fields, when deleting users from `User Information List`? This is my biggest concern right now with this method.

Comment: @Taurib No, it won't. But try this action on your test farm first so you get familiar with the process. I've done this several times, and it doesn't interfere with other objects of the site.